# Linq to SQL vs Access SQL - Why aren't Take() and TOP the same?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Sorry I couldn't come up with a better title, but it's kind of a convoluted question to begin with.

I'm in the process of converting an access database over to the web, and I'm using linq to sql.

In the access database, there is a SQL function that returns the top 3 records, ordered descending by # of individuals collected. For example, in a data set that has the following # of individuals collected as 37,10,9,9,9,5,4,1,1, the query (using TOP 3) returns 37, 10, 9, 9, 9

This is currently the desired effect, as no DISTINCT is wanted for this particular result.

However, in linq-to-sql using Take(3), the returned result is 37,10,9 --- taking 3 records. no surprises.

My question is- how would I get linq to return the same result as the original access SQL? I know I can do this by looping through the code and checking each record til i get 3 distinct, but that seems a little silly to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var topThree = collection.OrderByDescending(c => c).Distinct().Take(3);
var top = collection.Where(topThree.Contains).OrderByDescending(c => c);
```

That should do what you want.  You could easily wrap it into an extension method.

Comment: You'll need to include the ordering on your `top` query too: `var top = collection.Where(topThree.Contains).OrderByDescending(c => c);`

Comment: exactly what I needed, thanks! side note, this led me to find an error in Access when it was the 2nd number that was duplicated, ie 47, 11, 11, 7... Access would only count the first three, not all 4. inconsistencies, sheesh.